# How do I cange the cycle settings for Multiple objects - Blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I need two renders and for the second one I do not need the gloss for multiple objects on the floor. It would be difficult to deselect the gloss property for every object for 50 different objects. Is there a way to apply cycle property change from one active object to all selected?

Also is there an easier way to extract just the reflections from a glossy surface, currently I am using different renders and the difference matte in the compositor.

I'm new to blender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of options in blender could be copied from active to other selected with Copy to Selected operator from context menu, including `cycles_visibility.glossy`

[image: Copy to Selected]

You can extract the reflections from some surfaces in Compositor using Object, Material ID or awesome Cryptomate feature and so on:

[image: extract the reflections]

Comment: Is there a shortcut key for the paste property? And also, by saying extract gloss, I mean that, reflection of one surface over the other, like a shadow catcher, but for gloss, a transparent image with the gloss of one object over the surface of another transparent surface?